# Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement'

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I'm embedding a YouTube iframe (in combination with their JavaScript API) in my website. I'm waiting for a specific event to trigger the `playVideo` function to start the player.

On mobile devices the method written above doesn't work. I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture
```

So my question:

Is it possible to bypass this kind of "limitation"?
I've already seen some native implementations in combination with a WebView and turning this "feature" off, but that's not exactly what I want. It would be my plan B.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to webview settings:

> settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);